# How to write single line blocks

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, block

I find myself trying to use single line blocks but end up having to break up into multiple lines anyway.  My most recent example is that I'm trying to get initials from the `name` field of an active record object.

```
@employee.name = "John Doe"
```

and I want to return `"JD"`.

The only way I knew how to do it was to initialize a string, then split the name, then add to the initialized string.  At the very least how can I avoid having to initialize the empty string?

```
def initials # In model
    intials = ''
    name_array = self.name.split(" ")
    name_array.each  { |name| initials += name[0].capitalize }
    return initials
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me play with some proof of concept

```
class Employee 
  attr_accessor :name

  def initials
    @name.split(' ').map { |name| name[0] }.join
  end
end

e = Employee.new
e.name = "Foo Baz"
p e.initials # FB
```

Comment: might add capitalization to `name[0]` but other that perfect!

Comment: Also, you can call `.split` without the `(' ')` parameter and it will function the same.

Comment: If you're in Rails you can use `name.first` instead of `name[0]`

Comment: @sagarpandya82 is correct, which also allows you to use block shorthand notation. So you can do: `@name.upcase.split.map(&:first).join`. Slick!

Answer (score 2):

I'd try things like:

```
'John Doe'.scan(/\b[A-Z]/).join # => "JD"
'John Doe'.scan(/\b[a-z]/i).join # => "JD"
```

Any of these sort of expressions can break down with names with sufficient complexity:

```
'John Doe-Smith'.scan(/\b[a-z]/i).join # => "JDS"
'John Doe Jr. III'.scan(/\b[a-z]/i).join # => "JDJI"
'Dr. John Doe MD'.scan(/\b[a-z]/i).join # => "DJDM"
```

Then it becomes a case of needing to strip out the parts that you don't want.